# Command line from Python 3

Tags: python

I have 1 python 3 script. I need to use another script via command line. What function should i use?
I mean something like that:

```
res = execute('C:\python32\python Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\start.pyw start=1 module=server > Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\test.html')
```

Comment: By `res =`, do you mean you want to save the standard output of the script?

Comment: If you don't mind installing a module, [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/) is very nice.

Comment: @DavidRobinson , yes, i mean that.

Comment: I doubt that you get much out of STDOUT, as it is redirected to a file in the shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. That gives you the most flexibility.

Comment: i found subprocess.check_out(), but i didn't understand, what should i put in "args". How should i use this function with command from OP?

Comment: Start with `subprocess.call` which takes the elements of your command line as a list of strings, split on whitespace. Experiment with this function e.g. in the Python shell until you are comfortable. Start with some simpler commands than the one in your question. After that there is plenty of help about subprocess, both here on SO as on the Internet. Also see Pascal Rosin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Process Management section of the os module

http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os

os.popen will work well if you are interested in i/o with the process

Answer (score 0):

This is a python program you want to start. It would be better to import the module, run the method you want and write the output to a file.

However, this would be how you can do it via shell execution:

```
from subprocess import *
command_stdout = Popen(['C:\python32\python', 'Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\start.pyw', 'start=1', 'module=server'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
res = command_stdout.decode("utf-8")
fd = open('Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\test.html',"w")
fd.write(res)
```